# how to grab data-value from li tag with jquery after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, input

For grabbing a value from a `li` tag and putting into an input filed  i use the `data-value`.
My list tags look like this:

```
<li class="set-value" data-value="test">grab value</li>
```

The js:

```
$(".set-value").click(function(){           
       var s = this.dataset.value;                         
       $(".set-input").val(s);
});
```

My input field looks like this:

```
<input class="set-input" type="text" value="" />
```

When click on `grab value` it puts **test** in to the input.! That works 
fine! 
When i do submit the value, i use an ajax call. After the ajax call, all `li` tags are dynamically reloaded. Problem is: when i click again on **test**, sending the value to the input field does not work anymore. After a hard refresh, it DOES work again.
I checked the following after the ajax:

- jquery core file is still loaded
- the js is still in the DOM

So why it does not work anymore for the second time?

Comment: As the `li` elements are removed and recreated by the result of the AJAX request you need to use a delegated event handler. See the duplicate for more  information

Comment: the `li` tags are not removed! All the list tags are reloaded after the ajax call

Comment: As mentioned, read the linked article. But quick answer: use `$(document).on('click','.set-value',function(){` instead.

Comment: That's the same thing. You can't 'reload' HTML. You destroy the elements that are there and recreate.

Comment: I agree @Rory! This solved the problem! Thnx